# How to install Myriad Pro on Windows 7 with TeX Live 2013?

Tags: pdftex, minionpro

I was trying to install Myriad Pro into my TeX Live 2013 and it comes up with this error:

```
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex.exe (file pmyb8a.pfb): cannot open Type 1 font file for reading
```

Since there are lots of information on the Internet, but none are specific to TeX Live 2013. What I have done is as the following:

1. Install TeX Live 2013;
2. Use LCDF Tools to convert the `.otf` files to `.pfb` files;
3. Type in commands `texhash` and `updmap-sys`.

Then I got this error, but I am sorry this is not the whole story, since I don't really remember what I have done. I suspect what I have not done is the `.afm` files, or where to let the system notice there are the font files. So could anyone provide a solution for anyone who is using TeX Live 2013, but also want to use Myriad / Minion Pro?

**Edit:** I managed to get the Myriad Pro on the document. Which I have done the following:

1. Install TeX Live 2013;
2. Use LCDF Tools to convert the `.otf` files to `.pfb` files, *and correct them to the correct file names*;
3. Put the files into `\texlive\2013\texmf-dist\fonts\type1\adobe\minion` and `\texlive\2013\texmf-dist\fonts\type1\adobe\myriad` (You need to create these folders first)
4. Type in commands `texhash` and `updmap-sys`;

**Edit 2:**

1. Use the following commands in your document:

   - `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`
   - `\renewcommand*\sfdefault{pmy}`
   - `\usepackage{textcomp}`

And, finish...

Comment: You don't need the afm files. You only need the tfm's, which are made by the lcdf type tools, and the pfb's.

Comment: Where can I get the .tfm file?

Comment: In addition, where should I put the files into?

Comment: `texmf-local`, the structure has to match the structure seen in `texmf-dist`, i.e. the folder structure under `fonts`

Comment: I allow myself to welcome SHY.John to TeX.SX  (speaking on behalf of the whole community). @SHY.John: You can have a look at our [starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: The .tfm's have tobe in texmf-local\fonts\tfm\myriad.

Comment: It's 2014. Please forget about Type 1 fonts and use OpenType fonts with LuaTeX or XeTeX.

Answer (score 2):

Use [FontPro](https://github.com/sebschub/FontPro/), which includes support for Myriad Pro.

Comment: So that means I need Cygwin?

Comment: Yes. Or a Linux VM. At least if you want to use this script.

Answer (score 2):

Well you can simply use the original otf (open type format) by compiling with `xetex`. In fact is what I do with myriad pro.

Comment: With xetex or lualatex, the math support is limited without any further work, though.

Comment: That's right but nobody wrote before that need to use myriad pro for maths. In fact in the CTAN there is a math symbols for use with this typeface. We can use LaTeX for compose more than math, much more.